# Are there any plants that give aroma day and night?

Tags: houseplants, plant-recommendations

There is a plant which gives aroma in the night; I do not know its name but I have seen it somewhere.

Are there any plants that give aroma day and night?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - some plants produce their perfume when its dark and others during the day. Some produce the most intense perfume as dusk falls, but not after dark. I can't think of any single plant which produces perfume 24 hours a day, other than one I can't recall the name of which apparently stinks rather than being pleasantly scented - that one may stink all the time the flower is present, I'm not sure. There wouldn't really be any advantage in their doing it - those which produce their perfume after dark do so as a 'lure', if you like, to encourage night insects to visit, either for the plant to consume or simply for pollination - they've just evolved that way.

Comment: Can you name those plants which produce perfume in dark and the ones which produce in day? Also would they grow in Bangalore, India?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, no, not without research, other than Zaluzianska ovata, which opens its flowers at dusk and is highly scented. South African in origin, so may well grow where you are.